Unmatched Route in Expo React native
I am trying to implement deep linking in my expo-react native app, I have configured linking, but when I open a deep link, it says unmatched route, when I click on go back, the same page loads with out a problem, any help would be appreciable
const prefix = Linking.createURL('/');
  const linking = {
    prefixes: [prefix],
    config: {
      screens: {
        
        Invite: 'invite/:id',
        
      },
    },
  };
 <NavigationContainer independent={true} linking={linking}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
<Stack.Screen name="Invite" component={myscreen} options={myoptions} />
      </Stack.Navigator>

trying to open a screen with deep link, but it gets into unmatched route page

Share your deep link.

myapp://invite/16

Have you specified myapp scheme in app.json?

Yes i did, interesting thing is, when i click on go back on the unmatched error page, it navigates to invite/16 which is the correct route, i am suspecting of the navigation library version causing the problem, will try to downgrade and test them

Figured out the problem, i created the app with expo router which has a different url structure

Figured out the problem, i created the app with expo router which has a different url structure – expo-router doesn't need any configuration for deep links, we need to browse with file structure e.g. myapp://path/file name/?param=value
